# Is there a way for exact positioning with string's PadLeft?

Tags: c#, wpf, string, padding

I would like to marshal colon's vertically ,but there is a gap between them depending on character sizes.

I use `stringExpression1.PadRight(11)`  for all of the lines.

Is there a built in method or do I need to `measure` character's widths to make it better view?

**Note: They must be string I can't use a visual component ,such as `TextBlock`**

[image]

Comment: you need to measure (Graphics.MeasureString) or use a [mono-spaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces)

Comment: The answer is `NO`, you may have to use some `fixed-width font`.

Comment: Where do you list these strings, in a winforms `TextBox`?

Comment: I see where your going with that Tim...

Comment: @TimSchmelter it is a WPF . But it is a tool-tip of a chart and chart accept just `object` as tooltip text. I could not find a template for this tooltip. So.. I also do not know which font it uses.

Comment: @Sayse What do you mean ? What did you see ? I would like to see too.

Comment: I believe he was thinking that you could just align the controls (i.e labels) to the right which would inheritantly align the text

Comment: @Sayse Yes I expected it and noted it bold. I will try your suggestion by default fonts. I've learnt that default WPF font is Tahoma. It might helps.

Comment: Yes, i thought that you could use the control itself or the arrangement of controls to align it. In webforms you would also have css. Sometimes a different control is a viable solution. But in this case i have no idea.

Comment: Why not use a templated tooltip?

Comment: @GarryVass because it activates tooltip when your cursor close to points. But there is no tooltip template option for it...It is not a classic tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tab` "\t". If the left side description like Systolic, Diastolic, etc, is constant then you could add appropriate number of `"\t"` to provide the correct spacing as shown below.

```
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}\t\t: {1}", "Systolic", 80));
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}\t\t: {1}", "Diastolic", 170));
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}\t\t: {1}", "Pulse", 50));
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}\t: {1}", "LooooooongDesc", 50));
        this.tb.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

EDIT from Sheridan >>>

In order for this to work in `WPF`, you will need to set the [`AcceptsTab` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.acceptstab.aspx) of the `TextBox` to `True`:

```
<TextBox AcceptsTab="True" ... />
```

Comment: The expressions;Systolic... are `Localized` so I can't do something like that. Beside this I can't reach `TextBox`. This is the lack of design of component. What is advantage of using `tabs` rather than `PadRight(11)` ?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't really helped but hope shows a way for s.one

Usage

```
            List<string> items = new List<string>() {        
                          UIResources.Systolic, 
                          UIResources.Diastolic, 
                          UIResources.Pulse };

            var result = GetAlined(items);
```

helper code

```
    const string EMPTYLINE="                                                                                                                                ";   
    public static int GetDefaultItemWidth(string text,System.Drawing.Font font=null)
    {
        if (font == null)
            font = System.Drawing.SystemFonts.DefaultFont;

        return System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, font).Width;
    }

    public static List<string> GetAlined(List<string> inputString)
    {
        double max = default(double);
        var spaceWidth = GetDefaultItemWidth(" ");
        foreach (var item in inputString)
        {
            var width = GetDefaultItemWidth(item);

            max = Math.Max(max, width);
        }

        List<string> resultItems = new List<string>(inputString.Count);
        foreach (var item in inputString)
        {
            var width = GetDefaultItemWidth(item);
            if ((max - width) > spaceWidth)
            {
                var spaceCount = (int)Math.Round((max - width) / spaceWidth);
                string resultItem = item;
                resultItem=EMPTYLINE.Take(spaceCount).ToString() + resultItem;
                resultItems.Add(resultItem);
            }
            else
            {
                resultItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return resultItems;
    }
```